# Queue song on Spotify Player via Web API

Tags: spotify

Is there a way via the Spotify Web API to queue a song to a user's queue on their active device?

I don't want to play the song from a web page.  I want to via a web page/server app call the Spotify Web API using the user credentials to add a track to their queue, which would play on their active Spotify device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no endpoint for queue (you can track the feature request [here](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/462))

There is an endpoint to play a track, which you can check out [here](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/start-a-users-playback/).